# запись данных в БД sqlite (Python)

Tags: python, sqlite

история такая, спарсил данные, получил список:

```
resu = ['P', '1', 'PEP Purpose and Guidelines', 'Warsaw, Hylton, Goodger, Coghlan', 'P', '2', 'Procedure for Adding New Modules', 'Cannon, Faassen', итд.....]
```

и из этого списка мне нужно создать БД где:

```
в колонке type_status: P (пример из списка resu (Выше)

в колонке number: 1

в колонке title: PEP Purpose and Guidelines

в колонке authors : Warsaw, Hylton, Goodger, Coghlan
```

я не понимаю и не могу найти уже второй день как мне из списка resu переместить эти данные в БД, очень прошу помочь

вот мой полный код:

```
    from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine, delete
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, declared_attr


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

PEP_URL = 'https://peps.python.org/'

session = requests.get(PEP_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(session.text, features='lxml')

numerical_index = soup.find(
    'section', attrs={'id': 'numerical-index'}).find_all('tr')

resu = []

for num in numerical_index:
    position = num.find_all('td')
    for i in position:
        resu.append(i.text)
print(resu)


class Base:

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)


class Pep(Base):
    type_status = Column(String(2))
    number = Column(Integer, unique=True)
    title = Column(String(200))
    authors = Column(String(200))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'PEP {self.pep_number} {self.name}'



engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlite.db')

session = Session(engine)
```

да, я понимаю что есть такая конструкция:

```
    session.execute(
    insert(Pep).values(
        type_status='',
        number='',
        title='',
        authors=''
    )
)
session.commit()
```

но я не понимаю как данные в нее записать из списка `resu`, там более 8000 значений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тоже встречалась такая задачка в практикуме, но там не было в условии выводить что-либо в терминал, тебе нужно было заполнить БД SQLite посредством SQLAclhemy, а данные взять спарсенной таблицы. Ниже моя реализация решения. Уверен, что есть более изящное решение)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declared_attr, declarative_base


PEP_URL = 'https://peps.python.org/'


class Base:

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)


class Pep(Base):

    type_status = Column(String(2))
    number = Column(Integer, unique=True)
    title = Column(String(200))
    authors = Column(String(200))


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlite.db')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = Session(engine)

response = requests.get(PEP_URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='lxml')

numerical_index = soup.find(
    'section', attrs={'id': 'numerical-index'}).find('tbody').find_all('tr')

for i in numerical_index:
    pos = i.find_all('td')
    session.add(Pep(
        type_status=pos[0].text,
        number=pos[1].text,
        title=pos[2].text,
        authors=pos[3].text,
    ))
session.commit()
```